# Jaspersoft Studio Spring Data Adapter Classpath

Tags: classpath, jaspersoft-studio

I want to create a Data Adapter in Jaspersoft Studio to use a `sessionFactory` bean defined in spring application context. However I get `ClassNotFoundExceptions` and `IllegalArgumentExceptions`. I tried to add  several versions of Spring and Hibernate jars to `Java Build Path`, but I get no success.

Does anyone know what libs do I need? I reviewed Jaspersoft oficial documentation, Jaspersoft forums, StackOverflow and google, and I can't find any clue about it.

It is getting me nuts!

Comment: Please post a more complete stacktrace. Also, please show your configuration for the build path.